# React Native module update code but react module embedded in React Native root app does not' affect?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules

I create react native module according to example on offical website at [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-setup).
My react native module name is `MyLibrary`. I add function in file RNMyLibraryModule.java,

```
@ReactMethod
  public void greeting(String message) {
    Log.e("HelloWorlModule", "Salution, " + message);
  }
```

in native module (MyLibrary) but that project was embedded in react native root app don't affect.
How should I do to code in embedded project always update same native module?

[image]

Thanks for all helping!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Can you please reframe your question ?

Comment: @SurajMalviya I use comman "react-native-create-library MyLibrary" to create native module. I add function greeting(String message) to print console log in Log cat of Android Studio but when run it show error message with mean don't exist function greeting(), if I add that function in embedded project same above, it will run ok. But git only detect file change in react native module, not embedded module.